# nodeJs How to use config with process.argv

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code, I have usernames on my config file and when I start my code with "node code.js randomusername" I want to get my password. I tried this code but it got undefined. How can I do that? I'm beginner of nodejs.

```
var config = require('./config.json');


console.log(config.process.argv[2].password);
```

Comment: Did you try `$ node code.js -- randomusername`?

Comment: I tried it but it got undefined again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(config[process.argv[2]].password);
```

What your code is currently trying to do is access a field named `process.argv[2]` in your `config` object. What you actually want is to access a field whose name is in the variable `process.argv[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package.

Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of NAME=VALUE. For example:

```
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Now you can access your env variable as below

```
var username= process.env.DB_USER,
var password= process.env.DB_PASS
```